# Excel 2016 - setting the upper bound of a chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a pair of clustered bar charts. I'd like to have them both be on the same scale - so say set the upper bound of both charts at 100,000,000 or whatever.

In other software I've used this is pretty obvious - somehow I'm not seeing the option in Excel.

From Googling it seems like it should be under the Axis Options - but, no?

[image: Screenshot of where I'd think those options should be]

Comment: I don't have access to 2016, but try unchecking the option to set it automatically based on data.  That might reveal additional options to manually set it.

Comment: I tried the same thing, but unfortuantely it does not.

Answer (score 2):

Got it.  So if you delete the numbers in the axis, then you lose the ability to set the max/min/etc. values for that axis, for some reason.

My charts had the numbers on the axis deleted because that would look cluttered and be pointless.  The workaround - keep the axis numbers there, just make them transparent.

Edit:  Though then the transparent numbers can still affect the formatting of the chart.  Turns out even better is to go to Axis Options - Labels - Label Position > None.  Just, don't click/delete the axis numbers directly, even though that's typically fine for other elements of a chart.